# Only portion of first and last ticks shown in x-axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm only see a portion of the first and last ticks in this d3.js graph:

```js
let margin = ({ top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 100 });
let dim = ({ height: 100, width: 500 });
let svg = d3.select('#foo');

svg.attr('height', dim.height);
svg.attr('width', dim.width);

let dateTimeExtent = [new Date('2023-12-07T08:02:38.000Z'), new Date('2023-12-07T08:10:46.000Z')];
let x = d3.scaleUtc()
  .domain([dateTimeExtent[0], dateTimeExtent[1]])
  .range([margin.left, dim.width - margin.right]);
let ticks = [dateTimeExtent[0], ...d3.utcMinute.every(5).range(dateTimeExtent[0], dateTimeExtent[1]), dateTimeExtent[1]];
/* ticks contains [
"2023-12-07T08:02:38.000Z",
"2023-12-07T08:05:00.000Z",
"2023-12-07T08:10:00.000Z",
"2023-12-07T08:10:46.000Z"
]*/

// x-axis
svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(0,${dim.height - margin.bottom})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickValues(ticks)
    .tickSizeOuter(0))
  .call(g => g.selectAll('.tick > text')
    .attr('transform', 'rotate(90) translate(23 -12)')) // <-- rotates axis tick
  .call(g => g.append('text')
    .attr('x', dim.width - margin.right)
    .attr('y', -4)
    .attr('fill', 'currentColor')
    .attr('font-weight', 'bold')
    .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
    .text(''));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <svg id='foo'>
  </svg>
</div>
```

In the graph I only see the seconds portion of the first and last ticks. The other ticks occur at 5 minute intervals and are showing as expected.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure why the problem occurs, it might be related to how you specify the tick values and formatting.

You can explicitly specify your time format with [d3-time-format](https://d3js.org/d3-time-format) like this :

```
const timeFormat = d3.utcFormat("%H:%M");
```

Then add it to your graph and you will be able to see the full dates :

```js
let margin = ({ top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 100 });
let dim = ({ height: 100, width: 500 });
let svg = d3.select('#foo');

svg.attr('height', dim.height);
svg.attr('width', dim.width);

let dateTimeExtent = [new Date('2023-12-07T08:02:38.000Z'), new Date('2023-12-07T08:10:46.000Z')];
let x = d3.scaleUtc()
  .domain([dateTimeExtent[0], dateTimeExtent[1]])
  .range([margin.left, dim.width - margin.right]);
let ticks = [dateTimeExtent[0], ...d3.utcMinute.every(5).range(dateTimeExtent[0], dateTimeExtent[1]), dateTimeExtent[1]];
/* ticks contains [
"2023-12-07T08:02:38.000Z",
"2023-12-07T08:05:00.000Z",
"2023-12-07T08:10:00.000Z",
"2023-12-07T08:10:46.000Z"
]*/


const timeFormat = d3.utcFormat("%H:%M");
// x-axis
svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(0,${dim.height - margin.bottom})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickValues(ticks)
     .tickFormat(timeFormat) // Format the tick values
    .tickSizeOuter(0))
  .call(g => g.selectAll('.tick > text')
    .attr('transform', 'rotate(90) translate(23 -12)')) // <-- rotates axis tick
  .call(g => g.append('text')
    .attr('x', dim.width - margin.right)
    .attr('y', -4)
    .attr('fill', 'currentColor')
    .attr('font-weight', 'bold')
    .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
    .text(''));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <svg id='foo'>
  </svg>
</div>
```

If you want to display your data in a specific way the [d3-time-format](https://d3js.org/d3-time-format)
  page got a lot of information regarding formatting

Comment: Thanks, that works in this example, but I'm using Typescript, and starting at line with `.call(d3.axisBottom(x)`, I get error `Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.`. `.tickFormat(timeFormat)` results in error `No overload matches this call.` There's no way to create a Typescript snippet.